# Get Nodes from XML having same parent and child name

Tags: c#, xml

```
    <maintag>
           <CENTER>
              <ID>11</ID>
              <CENTER>333</CENTER>
           </CENTER>
           <PRODUCTID>100</PRODUCTID>
           <LastNum>0900</LastNum>

    </maintag>
```

I have above XML where there is same tag name for parent and one of its child node i.e. CENTER. I know i can parse it in multiple steps going at index 0 of main tag , then index 0 of CENTER tag will give ID and Index 1 of center tag will give value 333 of CENTER etc. But is there a way where i can directly get values of both the ID and CENTER (11 , 333 ) directly.

Comment: The XPath "//CENTER[CENTER]/*" gives all children of the CENTER tag that has a CENTER tag as child, in this example ID & CENTER

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string xml = @"<maintag>
           <CENTER>
              <ID>11</ID>
              <CENTER>333</CENTER>
           </CENTER>
           <PRODUCTID>100</PRODUCTID>
           <LastNum>0900</LastNum>
    </maintag>";

      XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
      xd.LoadXml(xml);

      string center = xd.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("CENTER/CENTER").InnerText;
      string id = xd.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("CENTER/ID").InnerText;


    }
```

Comment: Sometimes I use the LINQ XML other times, this seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you a very general answer here:

```
 var elementsWithChildrenOfSameName = 
    xmlDoc.Root.Elements()
     .Where(ele => ele.Elements().Any(t => t.Name == ele.Name)).ToList();
```

From there you can easily get the data you want.

Or in a integrated query style:

```
 var elementsWithChildrenOfSameName = 
        from parent in xmlDoc.Root.Elements()
        from child in parent.Elements()
        where child.Name == parent.Name
        select parent; // Or maybe select the id's?
```

Answer (score 0):

LinqToXml XDocument query:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(x);
var res = doc.Descendants("CENTER")
             .Where(el => el.Elements("ID").Count() > 0 && el.Elements("CENTER").Count() > 0)
             .Select(el => new { 
                                 id = el.Element("ID").Value,
                                 center = el.Element("CENTER").Value 
                               })
             .ToList();
```

Select all CENTER tags, which have in children both ID and CENTER tags and take their ID and CENTER values into the new result collection.